# Changing a variable value within a query in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If someone can help me with this, I will appreciate it.

I have 2 tables in sql 2008:

```
[users]
  [userId] uniqueidentifier
  [beginningDate] datetime
and [items]
  [userId] uniqueidentifier
  [itemDate] datetime
```

I want to count the number of users that have at least one item in [items] from January to December of any given year, I do this:

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2014, @Month int = 1 --January
SELECT ISNULL(Count(*), 0)
FROM [users]
WHERE 
(
SELECT ISNULL(Count(*), 0) FROM [items] 
WHERE [users].[userId] =  [items].[userId] 
AND YEAR([itemDate]) = @Year
AND ( MONTH([itemDate]) >=  @Month AND MONTH([itemDate]) <=  12 ) 
) > 0
```

It works fine, the problem is that I want to check (and change accordingly), if the `[beginningDate]` is newer than `@Month /@Year` (it will always be the same year) then change the @Month variable to the `[beginningDate]` month value.

Comment: Seems like you should apply a CASE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in your where clause and use that to assign correct values to Month

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Allan S. Hansen for his reply.

I solved the problem by creating a function and calling it from my query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMonth]
(
    @UserId uniqueidentifier
    , @Year int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Month int = 1; --January
    DECLARE @DateValue DateTime
    DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime = CONVERT(nvarchar(4), @Year) +'-03-01' --de mar
    SELECT @DateValue =
    CASE 
        WHEN [beginningDate] > @DateFrom THEN [beginningDate]
        ELSE @DateFrom
    END
    FROM [users]
    WHERE [userId] = @UserId
    IF(@DateValue IS NULL)
        SET @Month = 1;
    ELSE
        IF(@DateValue > @DateFrom) SET @Month = MONTH(@DateValue)
    return @Month;
END
```

This is the new query:

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2014, @Month int = 1 --January
SELECT ISNULL(Count(*), 0)
FROM [users]
WHERE 
(
    SELECT ISNULL(Count(*), 0) FROM [items] 
    WHERE [users].[userId] =  [items].[userId] 
    AND YEAR([itemDate]) = @Year
    AND ( MONTH([itemDate]) >=  [dbo].[GetMonth] ([users].[userId], @Year) 
    AND MONTH([itemDate]) <=  12 ) 
) > 0
```

Thanks anyway to all

Saludos

rubenc